# How to use pgtype.Numeric with gorm and sqlite3?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I need to store very large and high precision numbers with gORM, and using a [pgtype.Numeric](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype#Numeric) seems like the best bet. However, I cannot because I get an error: `sql: Scan error on column index 4, name "foo": cannot scan int64`

My model looks something like this:

```
type Model struct {
    gorm.Model
    Foo *pgtype.Numeric `gorm:"not null"`
}
```

Not sure if using pgtype.Numeric is the best (that's what i've seen everyone else use), or I'm doing something wrong. Thanks!

The code that caused the error:

```
package main

import (
  "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
  "gorm.io/gorm"
  "math/big"

  "github.com/jackc/pgtype"
)

type Model struct {
  gorm.Model
  Foo *pgtype.Numeric `gorm:"not null"`
}

func main() {
  db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
  if err != nil {
    panic("failed to connect database")
  }
  // Migrate the schema
  db.AutoMigrate(&Model{})

  // Create
  db.Create(&Model{Foo: &pgtype.Numeric{Int: big.NewInt(10000000), Status: pgtype.Present}})

  var m Model
  db.First(&m) // this line causes the error
}
```

Comment: Show the code that produced the error.

Comment: Please also note on which line the error occurs. Also, that does not appear to be the complete error message. Omit sensitive information if really necessary, but please provide the full context of the error so that we can understand.

Comment: What is the type of the `foo` column in the database? Does the `db.Create` function return any kind of error? If not, what does the value stored in the database look like?

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite3 does not support big integer so there is no way you can accomplish that directly. I run the code and foo column is create as:

```
`foo` numeric NOT NULL
```

Which in sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html means

> A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five storage classes... If the TEXT value is a well-formed integer literal that is too large to fit in a 64-bit signed integer, it is converted to REAL.

So your big int will turn into float64. Good thing it paniced instead of losing accuracy silently.

What you can do is convert the big int to string or bytes first and store that.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging the `sql.Scanner` interface for database deserialization, it is noticeable that the value from the database arrives either as `int64` or `float64`. This then leads to the corresponding error message.

A possible solution is to use a `text` data type in the database, by adding the type `text` to the field tag:

```
`gorm: "type:text;"`
```

Using the `github.com/shopspring/decimal` package, you can conveniently create a decimal number using the `NewString` function.

The adapted code to insert the data:

```
num, err := decimal.NewFromString("123456789012345.12345678901")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
db.Create(&Model{Foo: &num})
```

The model structure might then look something like this:

```
type Model struct {
    gorm.Model
    Foo *decimal.Decimal `gorm: "not null;type:text;"`
}
```

This would result in the following schema:

[image: sqlite db schema]

**Test**

If one inserts a breakpoint in `decimal.Scan`, one can see that the value comes from the database as expected as a string, resulting in the creation of a decimal with `NewFromString` (see Decimal's [scan method](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal/blob/683f5e1a7e189020762b6ac3a0cd22276c136ee5/decimal.go#L1417)).

If you add this line of code to the end of the main function

```
fmt.Println(m.Foo)
```

it would result in the following output in the debug console:

```
123456789012345.12345678901
```

**Complete Program**

Your complete program, slightly adapted to the above points, would then look something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/shopspring/decimal"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Model struct {
    gorm.Model
    Foo *decimal.Decimal `gorm:"not null;type:text;"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    // Migrate the schema
    db.AutoMigrate(&Model{})

    // Create
    num, err := decimal.NewFromString("123456789012345.12345678901")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    db.Create(&Model{Foo: &num})

    var m Model
    db.First(&m)
    fmt.Println(m.Foo)
}
```

**pgtype.Numeric and SQLite**

If a PostgreSQL database is used, `gorm` can be used together with `pgtype.Numeric` to handle decimal numbers like `123456789012345.12345678901`. You just need to use the `numeric` data type on the Postgres side with the appropriate desired precision (e.g. `numeric(50,15)`).

After all, this is exactly what pgtype is for, see the [pgtype readme](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype) where it says:

> pgtype is the type system underlying the https://github.com/jackc/pgx PostgreSQL driver.

However, if you use a text data type in SQLite for the reasons mentioned above, `pgtype.Numeric` will not work with SQLite. An attempt with the above number writes `12345678901234512345678901e-11` to the DB and when reading it out the following error occurs:

```
sql: Scan error on column index 4, name "foo": 12345678901234512345678901e-11 is not a number
```